# Mongoose: how to model object hierarchy?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using Mongoose 2.7.0 with node.js.

How can I describe a schema with a single embedded object?

Effectively I want to end up my schema matching with a JSON structure like:

```
{
    title: "",
    position: {
       loc: [0, 0],
       street: "",
       zip: 1234,
       town: "Name"
    }
}
```

So far I've ended up with a solution like:

```
var MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String },
  position: {}
});
```

The problem in this solution is that it doesn't validate contents of `position`.

Comment: Did you try simply doing `position: { type: MyEmbeddedDocumentSchema }`? I don't have Node.JS at the moment (to test this), but I think it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to do something like this:

```
var MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String },
  position: {
    loc: [Number],
    street: String,
    zip: Number,
    town: String
  }
});
```